# How do I get the private key for a GoDaddy certificate so I can install it on Ubuntu 14+?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

The cert I have from StartSSL comes with a key file.  But from GoDaddy, I get only the 2 .crt files.  GoDaddy's instructions are for CentOS and explicitly do not work for Ubuntu.

How do I export the private key ... or get it from somewhere ... so I can use it with Apache SSL?  The question that is ALMOST the same as mine assumes use of a Mac Keychain application.  I don't run a Mac and I'm trying to do everything on the Ubuntu command line.  I know there's a way to do this ... can anyone help me find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Follow this steps.

1. First of all Generate the Private key and CSR using the following command.

   ```
   openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr
   ```

   You'll be asked the questions like the Country, State, City, Company Name, Domain name and all. Just fill up the details and your Private key will be ready as `server.key` in the directory you are going to run this command.

   You'll be asked to enter Challenge Password, You can enter any secure Password in there.
2. Login into GoDaddy and `ReKey` the Certificate, You'll have to Submit the CSR we've generated with the Private Key.

Once you'll `Rekey` the Certificate, you'll be able to Install the certificate using the `crt` file you got, `ca-bundle` you got and the Private key we just made!

Let me know if you have any questions about this.

PS: You have to use this method when you lose your Private key.

Comment: Thank you!  that was it!

Comment: Hi p01ymatch From where I can get `server.csr` file?

Comment: server.csr is an output file that will be generated when you execute this command.

Comment: thank you... And from where I can get `server.key`? please use `@`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, server.key is also an output file.

Comment: Thank you last question. I got two `.crt` files from the godaddy. Which one I need to use on server `ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt;` this?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, To properly install SSL Certificate, you need total 3 files. One will be server.key which you have generated by executing the command, The other two you got will be Certificate file and Chain File (The one with ca_bundle). You need all these files to install SSL. If you are configuring using Nginx, Join both the files you got in a single one and use it as value for `ssl_certificate` directive.

Comment: @AdarshSojitra After lot of struggle, this answer worked for me. Thanks adarsh!!!

Comment: godday does not provide private key directly?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding more detailed steps

On local windows command line

```
heroku login --sso // (on browser it will open the link - fill creds and done)

heroku apps // check your apps

heroku run bash -a <app-name>

openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr
```

It will ask few questions like Country,Email etc.. fill the info carefully

this will generate `server.csr` (request file) and `server.key` ( server.key )

copy this `server.csr` content file to godaddy's webiste, it will rekey and issue new certificate.

Download the public key

on heroku -> setting-> add/update certificate

copy public key downloaded from godaddy and private key generated on heroku server

thats all